# PHP: Waiting time so function can't be executed untill x minutes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to make a function for a small game, where I'am trying to look into setting a waiting time for x minutes, so that the script can't be refreshed whenever someone would like to. The plan is the following:

1. User uses the function via a normal input type="submit"- button
2. Function gets executed
3. A waiting time for 2 minutes get set
4. If the person visits the site that holds the script, a message will say "You have to wait x minutes untill you can redo the action". (if 2 minutes has not passed yet)
5. After 2 minutes the person will be able to see the same as in step one, and repeat the action.

Any suggestions to what functions I should look into in both PHP and MySql?
I am thinking having a table in MySql with a field called "last_executed", that will hold a timestamp for when the action was executed, all I think I need is a function that checks if 2 minutes has passed.

All suggestions are appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've suggested is almost certainly the best way to do it. Set the 'last_executed' using the PHP `time()` function, then compare it by:

```
$diff = time() - $last_executed; // $last_executed is the value from the server

if($diff < 120) { // 2 minutes in seconds
    echo 'No can do';
}
else {
    echo 'Go ahead';
    // Set the last_executed again in the database
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the function stores something into MySQL right? Why not put the timestamp of the last submitted entry in the row when you save it? Then just check that and compare:

```
// you need to check the database and get $timeFromDB from the thing that function is going to store
$lastStored = strtotime ($timeFromDB);
// get the current time
$currentTime = time ();
// figure out how much time has passed since the thing was last stored
$deltaTime = $currentTime - $lastStored;

// 120 seconds = 2 minutes
if ($deltaTime > 120) {
    // call the function
} else {
    // tell the user they have to wait $deltaTime seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get the time with button pressed. say it as `$time_pressed`.

So in php: `$time_btn_pressed =  (round(microtime(true), 2)*100)`

So further for any action get the current time and compare like:

```
$currentTime = (round(microtime(true), 2)*100) ;

if($currentTime - $time_btn_pressed >= 120){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely you would want to store the time the form was last submitted in session, then when getting back to the first page, either render the form, or the "please wait" message based on whether that time is set in session and if it is that the requisite time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the users last activity with

```
$waiting = new letUserWait();
$waiting->setConnection()->setActivityTime();
```

and check if he is allowed again with

```
$allowed = new letUserWait();
$allowed->setConnection()->isUserAllowed();
```

You can do this without Carbon if you want to, but I would recommend to add it, it's just more convenient. `$allowed` will be `true` if the user had no activity within the last 2 minutes.

```
<?php
namespace waitingTime;
use Carbon;
use PDO;

class letUserWait {

  protected $waitingTime;
  protected $dbconnection;
  public $UserAllowed;



  public function setConnection() {
     try {
        $this->dbconnection = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }



    return $this;
  }

  public function setActivityTime() {
    $stmt = $this->dbconnection->prepare('INSERT INTO user_waiting_time (user_id, timestart) VALUES (':user_id',NOW());
    $stmt->execute([':user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']]);

    return true;

  }

   public function isUserAllowed() {

       $stmt = $this->dbconnection->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM user_waiting_time WHERE timestart BETWEEN ".Carbon::now()->subMinutes(2)->toDateTimeString." AND ".Carbon::now());
       $stmt->execute();
       $rows = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
       $this->UserAllowed = true;
       if ($rows[0] > 0) {
       $this->UserAllowed = false;
       }

      return $this->UserAllowed;
  }

}
```